# Importing header file multiple times with C function in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, header-files

In my Xcode project I made a standalone header file with the following C utility function:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
CGFloat DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    CGFloat dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    CGFloat dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
};
#endif
```

Even with the preprocessor directives, if I try to `import` or `include` that header file in multiple locations, I receive the following error complaining about duplicate symbols:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Is there a different way I can achieve this effect?  This question is out of curiosity more than anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your function body in a `.c` file and the function declaration (aka prototype) in the `.h` with those `#ifndef`, etc. Then use `include` to import the header file where you need the function.

Remember to check the target membership of the `.c` file, otherwise it won't be compiled.

For a small function like that you can declare it `inline` and just use the header file:

```
inline CGFloat DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    // code as is
}
```

The compiler will **replace** your function calls with the function code without actually building and linking a new object file. No more duplicated symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function's definition is in the header, you get one definition of the function in each file (actually, each  translation unit) where it is included.

Move the function body into a ".c" file, leaving a declaration in the header, or declare it `inline`.